# Laravel : Join within query using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have a five tables in which i need to get data from all this.
`post,product,categories,attributes,post_attribute`

I have a query in my model that collect all post for a one product and it contains categories and attributes details .
Query :

```
 Post::with(['product.categories.attributes'])->whereStatus("Active")->get();
```

Response:

```
 "PostDetails": [
    {
        "id": 153,
        "user_id": 3,
        "product_id": 1,
        "demand_or_supply": "Demand",
        "description": "This is a post description three",
        "image_one": null,
        "image_two": null,
        "image_three": null,
        "image_four": null,
        "status": "Active",
        "created_at": "2018-05-07 09:51:08",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-07 09:51:08",
        "product": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Diamond",
            "icon": null,
            "status": "Active",
            "created_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:28",
            "updated_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:28",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "product_id": 1,
                    "title": "Shape",
                    "status": "Active",
                    "sort_order": 1,
                    "created_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:28",
                    "updated_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:28",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "product_id": 1,
                            "category_id": 1,
                            "parent_id": null,
                            "title": "Round",
                            "status": "Active",
                            "sort_order": 2,
                            "created_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29",
                            "updated_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "product_id": 1,
                            "category_id": 1,
                            "parent_id": null,
                            "title": "Princess",
                            "status": "Active",
                            "sort_order": 1,
                            "created_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29",
                            "updated_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "product_id": 1,
                            "category_id": 1,
                            "parent_id": null,
                            "title": "Oval",
                            "status": "Active",
                            "sort_order": 3,
                            "created_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29",
                            "updated_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "product_id": 1,
                            "category_id": 1,
                            "parent_id": null,
                            "title": "Kite",
                            "status": "Active",
                            "sort_order": 8,
                            "created_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29",
                            "updated_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 5,
                            "product_id": 1,
                            "category_id": 1,
                            "parent_id": null,
                            "title": "1-5",
                            "status": "Active",
                            "sort_order": 4,
                            "created_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29",
                            "updated_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 6,
                            "product_id": 1,
                            "category_id": 1,
                            "parent_id": null,
                            "title": "6-10",
                            "status": "Active",
                            "sort_order": 9,
                            "created_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29",
                            "updated_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 8,
                            "product_id": 1,
                            "category_id": 1,
                            "parent_id": null,
                            "title": "-2",
                            "status": "Active",
                            "sort_order": 10,
                            "created_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29",
                            "updated_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 9,
                            "product_id": 1,
                            "category_id": 1,
                            "parent_id": null,
                            "title": "+2 -4",
                            "status": "Active",
                            "sort_order": 7,
                            "created_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29",
                            "updated_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 10,
                            "product_id": 1,
                            "category_id": 1,
                            "parent_id": null,
                            "title": "+4 -6 1/2",
                            "status": "Active",
                            "sort_order": 6,
                            "created_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29",
                            "updated_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:29"
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

There is another table called `post_attributes` in this table I store `attribute_id` and `product_id` which is belongs to `attribute` and `product` table.

I want to filter `attributes` data which is only available in `post_attributes` table and only for 'product' which is available on `post_attributes` table with `product_id` and `attribute_id`.
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To constraint eager loading relations you can pass a closure to the eager loading query, and to query a relation you can use `whereHas` function, so it would look something like this:

```
Post::with(['product.categories.attributes' => function($query) {
    // Eager load constraint
    $query->whereHas('post_attribute', function ($query) {
        $query->where('product_id', 1); // Filter by the joined data
    });
}])->whereStatus("Active")->get();
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'`

Comment: @Javed Sorry, that was a typo