# Laravel : unexpected function (T_Function) in query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I just write a query to get all post data and it related to other tables. When i try to load inner query it returns error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION), expecting ']'

My model code :

```
Post::with('product.categories.attributes' => function() {
                        $query->whereHas('post_attribute', function ($query) {
                            $query->where('attribute_id',   '=', 'attributes.id' ); 
                        });
                    })->whereStatus("Active")->get();
```

What is the problem in my query.

Comment: `'product.categories.attributes' => function () { ....`

Comment: @linktoahref update code get same error, check query

Answer (score 1):

You have an syntax error while [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) . You should pass `relationship` as key and closure as value in the array

```
Post::with(['product.categories.attributes' => function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('post_attribute', function ($query) {
        $query->where('attribute_id', '=', 'attributes.id');
    });
}])->whereStatus("Active")->get();
```

Comment: `product.categories.attributes` this table in a relationship..now there is another table `post_attributes` i want to compare `attribute_id` with `post_attributes` table.

Comment: @Javed Sorry I don't have any clue for that query. May be you could ask a new question or update your current question with relevant details

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215037/laravel-join-within-query-using-eloquent` look this for me..